# center text vertically relative to image

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm building a website and like to have the logo of the organisation at the top of the page including the name next to it vertically centered.

This is the code I'm using at the moment:

```
<div style="height: 10em; position:relative;">
<div>
<img style="float: left; margin: 25px 25px 25px 0;" src="images/svg/erv.svg" alt="ERV logo 2020" width="74" height="100" />
</div>
<h1 style="margin:0;position: absolute;top: 50%;left: 50%;margin-right: -50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%) ">
Evangelische Roze Vieringen Amsterdam</h1>
</div>
```

[have a look here: it is the site I am building](http://dev.erv.amsterdam/actueel/erv-live)

It works nicely as long as the page is wide enough, but the text gets on top of the image when the screen is smaller.

Obviously I want the text to stay to the right of the logo. I understand that I need to include the image in the , but then the text does not center vertically... so who can help me here?

Thanx,

Thom

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website OR off-site example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the text is aligned to center and in smaller view the width percent is bigger. If you want this method anyway try left: calc(50% + 74px) or the px you want for your image's width.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work: the whole text block moved to the left and off the page. According to W3Schools [https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp you can use calc() only for width of a div.

Comment: Ok I see the problem, type a space between the values and the "+" mark, so not 50%+100px, but 50% + 100px. If not working i have still a few ideas but those are require a little refactoring.

Comment: I tried this and it works: for anyone who wants to use it: be careful to add whitespace before and after the + sign. A big thanx to you, Ronald.

Comment: Nothing :), just watch out for other browsers than chrome and firefox. there may be bugs but google for prefixes